# Angularjs ng-show waiting for population of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-show` to show an error based on an array, the usage is `ng-show="!items.length"` Because the items is being populated after a request, this flickers for a second before the items are populated.  Is there a way to wait for this to populate or for the `items` to be attached to scope?

Thanks!

Comment: does this help? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it just putting an extra control to your `ng-show` condition...

Try this

```
ng-show="items && !items.length"
```

here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/jY7ibonvx9IrNuYf6F8H?p=preview) demo

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too when working with promises. Another fix to assign the variable to the page and then assign a second variable to the first:

```
var arrayPromise = Service.getServiceCall();
arrayPromise.then(function(data){
  $scope.array = data;
});
```

This prevents the array being pushed to the page before the information is returned from a service (or whatever is providing the data after page load).